# How to center a link in a <div>

Tags: html, hyperlink, center

I need help to center a link in a div. horizontal and vertical align, I dont know how it works I test multiple possibilities but I failed.

```
.Menu {

height:81px;
left : 0px;
right : 0px;

border:1px solid #727272;
border-radius:9px;
-webkit-border-radius:9px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #333;

background-color: #FFFFFF;

margin:5%;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-left : 25%;
}


    .Picto {
position:absolute;
left : 7%;
height:42pt;
width:42pt;
}


a {
text-decoration : none;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
color: #666;
}
```

html :

```
<a href="trav.html"><div class="Menu" style="display:none;" id="Trav"><img src="img/trav.png" alt="Travaux" class="Picto"/>Travaux</div></a>
        <a href="arbo.html"><div class="Menu" style="display:none;" id="Equi"><img src="img/arbo.png" alt="Equipements" class="Picto"/> Equipements</div></a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: If you take the time to format your code properly it will be easier for us  to help you

Comment: You want to center a link inside a div but in your code, the div is inside the link? It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.Menu {
    height:81px;
    line-height:81px;
    text-align-center; 
  }
```

for  vertical align middle

> line-height and height same amount

for horizantal align center

> use text-align

for image and text align middle use

> vertical-align:middle in image class

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correctly in your CSS try `content-align:center`. this is what I have used in every web page I have made and it has worked every time, also you would be better off with `posistion:relative` instead of `position:absolute`

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Lm11a0we/

Comment: Hello, it works the text is in the middle but the picture too (Picto), I Just want the text in the middle thanks you